# Libgdx trailing fireworks

Tags: textures, libgdx, sprite

I am working with Libgdx and trying to create fireworks that leave trail behind them as the pixels fall down.

Every `render()` step a `Pixmap` object is erased, a current state of fireworks particles is drawn on it, then texture is created from this pixmap and drawn on SpriteBatch, something like this:

`pixmap.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
pixmap.fill();
pixmap.setColor(fireworks.red, fireworks.green, fireworks.blue, fireworks.alpha)
for (int i=0; i<Constants.FIREWORKS_PARTICLES; i++){
    pixmap.drawPixel(fireworks.x[i], fireworks.y[i]);
}
texture.draw(pixmap, 0, 0);
batch.draw(texture, ...);`

Is there an efficient way to take all the pixels from previous pixmap drawing and lower their alpha value (And if it is lower than some threshold - make it 0) before adding the new frame, so it will look like a slowly disappearing trail behind the fireworks?

- There is more animated stuff, so I can't do anything "global" (Like changing GL accumulator values or getting the entire screen buffer with `glFramebufferTexture2DOES`)
- I've tried iterating over `pixmap.getPixels()` ByteBuffer (And changing every 4th byte), but  it isn't working for me (Guess not familiar enough with BytesBuffers to make it tick)
- There was a topic with a suggestion about drawing an alpha-blended version of previous image and I've tried several variations of this technique, but couldn't find how to decrease alpha on older image and blend it with current batch (or texture).

Would highly appreciate any help (and general thoughts about the way I chose to draw the fireworks).

Comment: Take a look at `ParticleEffects`. They do exactly what you like to do.

Comment: The same problem stands. I made a fireworks effect, but can't make the particles leave a trail

Comment: @Vasisualiy I'm looking for a solution for this too. Did you find one?